# How to configure FLINK_CONF_DIR for standalone cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have a stand-alone Flink cluster with 2 Job Managers and 3 task managers. I am using Flink 1.15.1

While starting cluster on active job manager, I exported FLINK_conf_dir before start-cluster.sh

While my active job manager is able read Flink-conf.yaml that I configured, task managers are reading from default location.

How to do pass /configure flink_conf_dir for taskmanagers?

I wanted to see if env.ssh.opts will help but I am not sure how to do that